# Reading a specific time file and writing the contents to another one

Tags: c#, file-io

At runtime, I want to read all files who has the time stamp of a particular time. For example: if the application is running at 11:00:--, then it should read all files which is created after 11:00:00 till now(excluding the present one) and must write in the present file..I have tried like:

```
string temp_file_format = "ScriptLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH");
string path = @"C:\\ScriptLogs";
var all_files = Directory.GetFiles(path, temp_file_format).SelectMany(File.ReadAllLines);
            using (var w = new StreamWriter(logpath))
                foreach (var line in all_files)
                    w.WriteLine(line);
```

But, this doesn't seems to be working.No error..No exception..But it doesn't read the files, while it exist.

Comment: You need to specify a [*wildcard pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#File_and_directory_patterns) if you want to match multiple files. Check the [MSDN page for `Directory.GetFiles`], Remarks section, Wildcards table. Note the `*` wildcard in the example on that page also. Your example will only match files with that exact name, without an extension, and not files which *begin* with that name. Most likely, you simply need to add the `*` character at the end to indicate you want to match zero or more characters after `HH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern parameter of the GetFiles method should probably also include a wildcard, something like:

```
string temp_file_format = "ScriptLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH") + "*";
```

This will match all files starting with "ScriptLog_13_09_2013_11"

Answer (score 0):

As @Edwin already solved your problem, I'd just like to add a suggestion regarding your code (mostly performance related).

Since you are only reading these lines in order to write them to a different file and discard them from memory, you should consider using [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) instead of `File.ReadAllLines`, because the latter method loads all lines from each file into memory unnecessarily.

Combine this with the `File.WriteAllLines` method, and you can simplify your code while reducing memory pressure to:

```
var all_files = Directory.GetFiles(path, temp_file_format);

// File.ReadLines returns a "lazy" IEnumerable<string> which will
// yield lines one by one
var all_lines = all_files.SelectMany(File.ReadLines);

// this iterates through all_lines and writes them to logpath
File.WriteAllLines(logpath, all_lines);
```

All that can even be written as a one-liner (that is, if you are not paid by your source code line count). ;-)